# How do i get IDs from multiple rows without using AND

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem that I am not able to solve. I am still a beginner in SQL and have no clue on how i should solve this problem.

Here is an example

If my database were to look like this:

```
id  tags_id clients_id

1   10      1
2   10      2
3   11      1
4   12      3
```

Now how would my query look like to be able to get the result of client_id 1?
I cannot use AND because since the rows are seperated it would not work. I have also tried using this query:

```
 SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tags_id IN (10, 11);
```

This would return the client_id 1 AND 2 but i only want 1.

It basically has to look something like this but then working ofcourse:

```
SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tags_id = 10 and 11
```

and it has to return the clients_id 1
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please draw your query for this :  SELECT * FROM tags WHERE 'tags_id IN ('.implode(',',$criteria['tagList']).')';

Comment: the first query you have should actually do the trick! (apart from wrong single-quotes `'` in there)

Comment: You can't use AND because you're supposed to use OR... `WHERE tags_id = 10 OR tags_id = 11` or `WHERE tags_id IN (10,11)` both will work the same.

Comment: What is the structure of $criteria['tagList']

Comment: Sorry, I missed and miswrote my question and edited it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution using IN is correct but you seem to have a syntactical error.

Try removing the single quotes surrounding the condition.

`SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tags_id IN (10, 11);`

With PHP code in the style of your example this would be:

`$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tags_id IN ('.implode(',',$criteria['tagList']).');';`

*Note that the tags_id column name is not included in a quote.*

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

One of the more simple approaches, assuming your table contains only unique relationships is to only keep the rows with client_ids that matches the same amount of times as the number of tags_id you have in your IN clause.

```
SELECT client_id, 
       COUNT(client_id) AS client_count
FROM adlibris_odladev.test 
WHERE tags_id IN (10, 11)
GROUP BY client_id
HAVING client_count = 2;
```

What we're doing here is counting how many times each client_id matches and using HAVING filter out all client_ids that do not exist 2 times in the result set.

To make this dynamic with PHP you want to replace the `(10, 11)` clause with an `implode(',', $ids)` like you had before and the `2` with a `count($ids)`.

Comment: Sorry, miswrote my question. I edited it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @kev Ok! Updated my answer, hopefully I've understood the question correctly.